# How to fix sbt reporting "Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.io.EOFException"?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

While running `sbt` command in an empty directory, it keeps failing with the following exception:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.io.EOFException
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:11)
    at sbt.WrapUsing.open(Using.scala:36)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:778)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:777)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:777)
    at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
    at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:29)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:23)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:770)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:766)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:264)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:254)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:163)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:78)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$gzipInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:91)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$gzipInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:91)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$1.openImpl(Using.scala:56)
    at sbt.WrapUsing$$anonfun$open$2.apply(Using.scala:36)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:11)
    at sbt.WrapUsing.open(Using.scala:36)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:778)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:777)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:777)
    at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
    at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:29)
    at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:23)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:770)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:766)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (compile:copyResources) Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.io.EOFException
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

What can be the root cause of the issue?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It appears that the exception has been due to some problems with the local repo. After cleanup, e.g. removing `target` directories from `~/.sbt` directory it's now working fine.

```
jacek:~/.sbt
$ find . -name target | xargs rm -rf

jacek:~/sandbox/stackoverflow/testaaa
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to testaaa (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/testaaa/)
[testaaa]>
```

I found the solution in the thread [[2.1.1] SBT: InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.io.EOFException](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/7KUtauaxnoo/XoHaTwZhPpAJ.) in the play-framework forum.

---

I was also told that the issue goes away after removing all `target` directories in the project's home directory, e.g. `target`, `project/target`.

```
jacek:my-project-path
$ find . -name target | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Speaking in batch language:
for /d /r . %d in (target) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"

Answer (score 8):

go to the project directory

```
$ cd my-spark-app
$ rm -rf target
$ cd project 
$ rm -rf target project
```

now start sbt

```
$sbt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run `sbt clean` on your directory (to remove the `target` and any files in `/src` that might have been created earlier) and now try running `sbt`.
Had this issue when trying to create an Akka HTTP seed project by running `sbt -Dsbt.version=0.13.15 new https://github.com/akka/akka-http-scala-seed.g8`. My mistake was that I was not inside an empty directory while running the command.
More info about the error can be found [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3050)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:You need to add sbt path in .bash_profile in case of windows need to add environment  variable then go to terminal and run ./sbt file.

Step 2:delete target folder from your project directory.

Step 3:run sbt command from intellijID terminal "sbt clean" then "activator clean" then activator update".